# How to block until initdb has finished running in a Docker Postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'd like to use Docker to load a .sql file into a PostgreSQL database and serve it.

The following command returns quickly (before the database has been fully populated - which appears to happen asynchronously in the background).

```
docker run \
    --name myContainer \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -v mySqlFile.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql \
    -d postgres:alpine
```

Since this command will be part of a script, I'd like the command to block until the database has fully initialised with `mySqlFile.sql`

How would I go about getting the command to block, or some other means of pausing while `mySqlFile.sql` is loaded?

For clarity: I run the above command, and then the following command:

```
echo "select count(*) as \"Posts imported\" from posts;" | docker exec -i myContainer psql -U postgres
 Posts imported
----------------
              0
(1 row)
```

Waiting a few seconds, and I get this:

```
echo "select count(*) as \"Posts imported\" from posts;" | docker exec -i myContainer psql -U postgres
 Posts imported
----------------
          51103
(1 row)
```

This is a problem, because I am looking to build an automated solution. I want the docker run command to block until all records have been imported into Postgres. Then I have the database in a state which is ready for the next command.

Comment: Your docker will run when mount is complete. Then PostgreSQL service will automatically block until all script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` has been executed

Comment: what about running a bash scrip instead of psql ... inside sleep for 15 seconds then execute the psql command?

Comment: Thanks @Urban48 but I'd prefer not to use sleep statements as I cannot predict how large the sql dump will be. 15 secs could be way too long (which is kinda okay)... but it could be too short (then my script will break)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. I think you can use this way.

When you run your `postgres` image, ENTRYPOINT is a shell.

In that time if you run `ps aux`, you will see that `PID 1` is `bash`.

But when all initialization is completed, `postgres` becomes the main process for `exec "$@"`. That time **`PID 1`** is `postgres`.

You can use this hack. You don't know when your initialization will be completed. But you are sure that, when your initialization is completed, your **`PID 1`** will be `postgres`.

```
$ docker exec -i myContainer ps -p 1 -o comm=
```

This will return `bash` when initialization is running. And will be changed to `postgres` when everything is done.

Of course, you need loop. But in this way you will be sure when initialization is totally completed without any guess.

**UPDATE**

As you are using alpine image, it has cut version of `ps`. You need to install uncut `ps` in your alpine image. (stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48655709/1924666))

Run following command first.

```
$ docker exec -i myContainer apk add --no-cache procps
```

Now `ps -p 1 -o comm=` will work

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately that particular ps command didn't work in my environment. I appreciate the cleverness of your solution though and will see if I can work with it as a starting point.

Comment: Yes. I missed it. you are using alpine.

Comment: @ChrisBeach, can you check now?

Comment: hey @aerokite, do you have a sample how I can make your suggestion into a loop so that I can pause my script until it returns postgres?

Answer (score 4):

Idea: creation of a custom wrapper waiting a specific record inserted in a table for docker at the end of the populate script.

Using `docker-compose` you  can use a custom wrapper script:

In a docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
     build: app/
     depends_on:
       - "db"
     command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "yourcommand", "with", "parameters"]
  db:
    build: db/
```

In wait-for-postgres.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"
#wait postgres up
until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

#wait populate script
while ! psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -t -c "select * from docker_ready" | egrep .
do
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo "Postgres is populated - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

You can find some tips on https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/, 
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately the database comes up (and down) during the initdb phase, so this check isn't able to distinguish the end of the initdb process

Answer (score 1):

> the temporary daemon started by **initdb** for these initialization scripts listens only on the Unix socket

You could use this fact that [temporary server is not available via TCP/IP](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts) and we could wait until that:

```
pg_isready -h localhost
```

And corresponding healthcheck:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h localhost -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```